# Limit is ignored in civicrm_api3('Membership', 'get')

Tags: civimember, api

Can anyone explain why limit here has no effect?  Still get 25 results every time.  Also tried `'api.Contact.get' => array(array('limit' => 1000))`

Using offset to recurse through the set works but is a nuisance.

```
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php';
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php';
 $config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton( );
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php';
 $result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'get', array(
    'membership_type_id' => "$level",
    'limit' => 1000,
    'api.Contact.get' => array(),
 ));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `options.limit` to make this work.

> options.limit : The maximum number of records to return. You can make this unlimited by setting the value to 0.

**Usage**

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'get', array(
  'membership_type_id' => "$level",
  'options' => array('limit' => 1000),
));
```

Get more details on the [different parameters you can use under `options`](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API#UsingtheAPI-Options).

Also check : [How do I get more than 25 records from the API?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/how-do-i-get-more-than-25-records-from-the-api/4339#4339)

Comment: Thank you.  For some dim reason I thought what I was passing was the options array...  Much obliged.